# avoiding conflicts in macro while using thirdparty c++ libraries

Tags: c++, macros, typedef, casablanca

I am trying to use Casablanca, http server. to do so, I need to include headers files from Casablanca, which contains few macro and typedef that cause issues in my project.

so my file look like this.

simplehttpserver.h

```
#include "cpprest/json.h"
#include "cpprest/http_listener.h"
#include "cpprest/uri.h"
#include "cpprest/asyncrt_utils.h"


SimpleHttpServer {

SimpleHttpServer(utility::string_t, std::function<void(http_request)> &request_handler); 

void OnInitialize();

void StartServer();
void StopServer();

private: 
 std::unique_ptr<http_listener> m_listenerUptr;
 // Handlers
 std::function<void(http::http_request)> m_all_requests;

 pplx::task<void> open() { return m_listenerUptr->open(); }
 pplx::task<void> close() { return m_listenerUptr->close(); }


 // SimpleHttpServer http_server_;
 utility::string_t address_;  

}
```

Say in my original code where I want to include this.

```
#include "simplehttpserver.h"
```

this causes all Casablanca header files pre-compiled into my project which conflicts with macros and typedef in my project. 
e.g. __declspec

I don't want to change my macros cause that will be lot of code change. and I don't want to change Casablanca header files, cause that will also cause long term maintenance overhead.

I am sure, this must be very common problem in c++, can someone please help me how can resolve this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: namespaces were invented to solve exactly this problem. If casablanca pollutes global namespace is rubbish, you just have to use different lib.

Comment: Also, a library that did use macros should be using names that would be near impossible to clash with any other name.  For example `CASABLANCA_MIN_VALUE` instead of just `MIN`.  Also `__declspec` is defined by Microsoft header, isn't it?

Comment: Neither your code nor a third-party library should `#define __declspec`. It's a reserved identifier.

Comment: Using C++ you have plenty of options to avoid macros in the first place

Comment: Personally, I think it is both the fault of the library to use "easy to duplicate" macro names, and your personal macros using "easy to duplicate" names.   That never works out well.

Comment: I agree with all the comments, but is there a way to solve this problem, can some one provide a sample or some pointer I can use ? :(

Comment: There is no simple general solution that will magically make your errors go away. You'll have to fix your macro names (shouldn't be all that difficult with a decent editor) or avoid using that library. You might be able to mitigate the problem to some extent by reducing the number of `#include`s. If you only need a tiny piece of the third-party library, you might be able to wrap it into your own abstraction and compile that as a separate translation unit with as few of your own headers `#include`d as possible.

Comment: What macros are specifically the problem? What platform are you building for?

You can generally solve these issues by #undef'ing the problematic macros before they interfere with other headers.